# In a Probability Space, what is the purpose of axioms $F_2$ and $F_3$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

When looking at these axioms [for a probability space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), I was wondering why union is used rather than intersection. But then I realised I didn't really understand at all the need for those axioms! Can anyone help explain?

$F_1 : \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}, \Omega \in \mathcal{F} \\
F_2 : \text{If } A, B \in \mathcal{F} \text{, then } A^c \in \mathcal{F} \text{ and } A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}\\
F_3 : \text{If } A_i \in \mathcal{F} \text{ for } i \geq 1 \text{, then } \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{F}$

Comment: Using both parts of axiom (2) you can get intersections...

Comment: @fluteflute and the other way around too, only then you can argue it makes no difference between taking union or intersection.